# JUICEUI-Block error

Tags: juice-ui

I am trying to add JuiceUi to an existing webforms application.
I want to use the Accordion feature but I get the following error. Can someone help?
Thanks

System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>). at System.Web.UI.ControlCollection.Add(Control child) at Juice.Framework.CssManager.Render(IEnumerable`1 referenceNames) at Juice.Framework.JuiceWidgetState.RenderCss() at Juice.Framework.JuiceScriptControl.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) at Juice.Accordion.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript code that has a popup with <% %>  tags caused this
e.g.

PopupModalDialog('AddTrans.aspx?regID=<%= CurrentRegID %>', '', 395, 230); error

Comment: Could you paste the control's code so that we can see where the offending line was? I'd like to try and prevent these errors in the future.